# audio recording button is not recording and playing that sound with circularprogressbarTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio-recording

I have two button action in my ViewController,One is `buttontapped`, another is `playButtontapped` and a view in which `circular progressbar` is assign. while pressing `buttonTapped` I'm not able to record audio and pause it. And `playbuttontapped` is disabled, due to this I'm also not able to play that recording further.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (player.playing) {
        [player stop];
    }

    if (!recorder.recording) {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive:YES error:nil];

        // Start recording
        [recorder record];
        [buttonRecord setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

        // Pause recording
        [recorder pause];
        [buttonRecord setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    //[stopButton setEnabled:YES];
    [_playButton setEnabled:NO];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(updateCircularProgressBar)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];

    NSLog(@"playTapped");
    if (!recorder.recording) {
        player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        //[player setDelegate:self];
        [buttonRecord setEnabled:YES];
        [recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)10];
        [recorder record];


}
}


- (IBAction)playbuttontTapped:(id)sender {
    if (!recorder.recording){
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }}
```

Comment: Check for userinteraction properties of button added on UIView. Please also ensure that your main thread is free to receive events from user.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS userinteraction properties of button added on uiview are good. what about mainthread? do you mean I have to do something in viewDidLoad? or what should I do to free main thread to receive events from user ?